# How to Remove Volkswagen Jetta 2007 Wheel

Tags: tires, vw, jetta, wheel-lugs

Can anyone tell me what to use to get this wheel off? I have a breaker bar but the lug bolt seems to be missing from the car.
[image: Picture of Wheel]

It has 9-points, so it is not an XZN triple square like I thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a plastic cap that covers a 17mm wheel bolt. There should be a little hook tool with the tools that came with the car to remove them. Or you can use a small screwdriver.

Comment: Or use anything else which will fit in there with a hook on it. The tool should be located in with the styrofoam where the spare is at ... also has a screwdriver and some other things in it.